# Number of common neighbors of any two adjacent vertices in a edge transitive graph is same or different?

Tags: symmetry

We have a theorem that, if the graph G is symmetric (both vertex and edge transitive) then G^p (by joining the vertices which are at the distance at most p in G) is also symmetric. See the reference ''Chromatic sets of power graphs and their application to resource
placement in multicomputer networks'' by N. Imani, H. Sarbazi-Azad, S.G. Akl, P. Moinzadeh;
Computers and Mathematics with Applications 58 (2009) 403–413.

But if you take Hypercube powers (Q_n)^p, the above question doesn't work out.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you give us an example where it fails?

Comment: Just a small note: Symmetric also requires that the graph be connected (This is also noted in the article). It seems that a simple induction on the distance suffices to prove the theorem, which is what is actually used in Theorem 2 of the paper you cite, with the automorphism also explicitly given.

Comment: Are you sure about it? Consider $(Q_n)^p$ for $p=2$. Let $v_0 = 0^n$: $v_1 = 10^{n-1}$ and  $v_2 = 110^{n-2}$. Is there mapping that maps the edge $(v_0,v_1)$ to $(v_0,v_2)$?